# Is it necessary to have openjdk 6 installed in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java, dependencies, openjdk

Is it necessary to have openjdk 6 installed in Ubuntu 12.04 or will openjdk 7 provide all the support I will need for Java functionality (generally speaking)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in this picture the OpenJDK 6 and 7 [share some code](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/) base:

[image]

OpenJDK 7 implement [newer features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/), while OpenJDK 6 is more used and therefore perhaps [more stable](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871048).

Also here is the OpenJDK [FAQ](http://openjdk.java.net/faq/).